# Backpack example "with-typescript" doesnt compile

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

node -v => v8.9.4
npm -v => 5.6.0

Want install [this](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/backpack/tree/master/examples/with-typescript) example.
There is a bug on example or im doing something wrong ?
I believe to install the example all you need to do is clone and run npm install but after doing it:

```
mkdir test
cd test
git clone https://github.com/palmerhq/backpack.git
cd ./backpack/examples/with-typescript/
npm install
npm run dev
```

I receive it:

```
| backpack-examples-with-typescript@0.5.0 dev ~/test/backpack/examples/with-typescript  
| backpack dev  


[at-loader] Using typescript@2.7.1 from typescript and "tsconfig.json" from ~/test/backpack/examples/with-typescript/tsconfig.json.  


[at-loader] Checking started in a separate process...  

[at-loader] Checking finished with 1 errors  


ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors 19:38:08  

error
```

Plus

```
[at-loader] ./src/main.ts:33:35  
TS2322: Type 'string | 3000' is not assignable to type 'number'.  
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.  

module.js:540  
throw err;  
^  

Error: Cannot find module '~/test/backpack/examples/with-typescript/build/main.js'  
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:538:15)  
at Function.Module._load (module.js:468:25)  
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:684:10)  
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)  
at bootstrap_node.js:608:3
```

I wrote [this question](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/backpack/issues/109) on they issue track days ago but no one answered

Comment: Have you opened up the files to check where the stack trace is pointing to? It looks like it is a port number number and a path check statement. Check line 33 in /src/main.ts. It is not able to resolve a dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It goes wrong at [this line (33:35)](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/backpack/blob/master/examples/with-typescript/src/main.ts#L33) of the source code. `process.env.PORT` is [typed as string](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/node/index.d.ts#L518) in the NodeJS type declarations. `getPort` however must return a number. Try changing the line with the following:

```
private getPort = (): number => parseInt(process.env.PORT) || 3000;
```

The additional error saying that a js file could not be found probably happens because `at-loader` just failed to compile, so it did not output that file.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this fixed, i will close the github issue pointing to your answer.